# Doctrine Inheritance Mapping design Pattern and performance

Tags: inheritance, design-patterns, doctrine-orm, mapping

In my project i want to use Inheritance Mapping but i don't known how to use this correctly and if it's interesting for performance and design Pattern.

I've got for example three entities

Event, EventFacebook, EventGoogle

I want to use Event as a MappedSuperclass and then have

Facebook and Google event's Entities as a child.

Those entities will contain specific fields.

What should i use :

- Use @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE") and why?
- Use @InheritanceType("JOINED") and why?
- Do not use Inheritance Mapping just empty fields and why?

Comment: Update your question and show the different properties for Facebook and Google events.  The number of different properties will dictate your choice between single table vs joined.  Use joined if there a bunch of differences.  Use single if they are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

By your description:

1. I want to use Event as a MappedSuperclass and then have
2. Facebook and Google event's Entities as a child.
3. Those entities will contain specific fields.  (speciallty this)

#### Single Table Inheritance does not apply

This inheritance is used when children have the same attributes. Take the following structure as example:

```
Image abstract class
 - name
 - size
 - extension
 + abstract manipulate();
```

Png Class extends Image

```
function manipulate(){
   echo "I am a PNG image";
}
```

GIFT Class extends Image

```
function manipulate(){
   echo "I am a GIFT image";
}
```

All the classes share the same attributes, then you can store all its data in a single table. Just need to mark a column as a type identifier, for exaple, the extension column.

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="extension", type="string")
@DiscriminatorMap({".png" = "PngClass", ".gift" = "GiftCLass"})

id_image | name | size | extension
1           a      10       .png    
2           c      8        .gift
```

#### Class Table Inheritance (this is the correct one)

By the simple reason that each class will have its own properties. So, parent table should keep the common data related with each child.

Image table

```
id |  name | size | extension
1      a      10       .png
2      b      8        .gift
```

Now, for example you want to track the duration of a gift movement. For the png image you want to set a maximun resize limit. Each property is unique for each class and semantically can be applied to the another one: a gift can not be resized neither a png can not has movement.

Png Table

```
id | limit
1  |  10x
```

Gift table

```
id | movement
2  |  5s
```

The id column is used to join parent-child data.

#### Considerations

- Very simple to manage dedicated objects with its own data.
- For loading an entity, doctrine make a query using join statement. For large databases this could impacts in time and more resources to load data.
- In this case, If the target-entity of a many-to-one or one-to-one association is an Image (CTI), you should keep this entity as simple as you can (avoiding other associations), because Doctrine could not make a proxy for the image class.

Comment: One thing is wrong here. Doctrine is smart enough to differentiate between 2 classes if using single table inheritance. The common fields should be in the mapped superclass, and the specific fields in the specific child classes. You will see that when doctrine creates schema, it will mark the specific fields in the child classes as nullable. That means you can save 2 entities with same mapped superclass but different fields in single table. The choice actually should be made for maintainability. if child classes have too many fields, go with multi table, if not you can use single table

Comment: Yeah,  smart enough.  Even you can map multiple classes with the same table.  However is illogic put in practice this methodology and should be avoided

Comment: Well the way you explained single table inheritance, `This inheritance is used when children have the same attributes` is not right from doctrine's mapped inheritance perspective. You may be right from a design perspective. The OP is asking specifically about doctrine. You dont need child class if the classes have same attributes ( or I would say fields) . see http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance. Also performance-wise single table inheritance is very efficient as no SQL JOINs are performed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.

After Reflection i'haven't got lot of differents properties for my EventFacebook and my EventGoogle.

I have tested

```
Use @InheritanceType("JOINED")
```

But this complicated my Model , add a JOIN to my Model , and the Design Pattern benefit was really limited.

So i choose to put some fields empty for futur performance.

When you see famous bundle like FOSUserBundle we could see empty fields.

It does not shock me to do that.

I hope it could help peoples who want to do that.